# windows backup server (windows server 2012 R2) difference in backup dates

Tags: windows, backup, network-attached-storage, qnap

Windows Backup Server is doing successful backups on a shared folder at QNAP NAS.

But dates of backups on the server and dates on NAS are different.

Last backup on the server was on 04.07.2021 and it was successful but on NAS it shows the date of 1st backup 02.07.2021....

I set up a scheduled backup so it works once a day.

Can someone explain to me if that is a normal thing or if there is some catch?

Comment: Likely, your NAS system time is off - you should keep it synchronized; at some point logins might also fail.

Comment: I agree, check the time of the NAS, most NAS allow setting up NTP or Similar jobs to synchronize the dates-  but the date on the NAS isn't required, as windows has this information already inside the files saved